# Low latency remote control within a local network (for games)

Tags: cross-platform, remote-access

I'm looking for a remote control solution that would allow for the best gaming experience within a home. The logic is simple: There is a powerful desktop computer  in the house  connected to a WiFi router, and some mobile devices. Let's say we're far away enough for Bluetooth input devices to be out of range of the desktop, but WiFi router's signal is still strong. The mobile devices are a rather weak netbook, a tablet, an phone with sufficiently large screen. For the input devices we have a keyboard, a mouse and some other bluetooth device (a ps3/ps4 controller) that doesn't work without some driver magic (but already configured to work with our desktop).

Can we play some games without noticeable lag with the server and client devices:

- Only relaying video output onto a remote screen (netbook, tablet, phone);
- Also using remotely connected control devices (mouse, keyboard, dualshock)?

I'm okay with complex solutions like separate video output relay thing and remote control using input devices connected to client device (as opposed to desktop computer we are streaming from).

Comment: I gotta say I tried both Teamviewer and Windows's standard remote connection, and both introduce a very noticeable lag. Not really playable unless it's a turn-based game.

Comment: I just tried VNC. It's just a little bit better than TV, but I guess this is as fast as it gets like this.

Comment: You can (and are welcome to) self-answer your question with VNC so the knowledge gets spread. Or if you ended up using something else, post that :)

Comment: That's what I usually do, but this is not the case unfortunately. Everything is still pretty laggy. I suspect this requires either very fast software processing or an external device specializing in fast video conversion. Either way I don't have any of that yet, so no hard facts to share :p